# Touch and Drag without using co-ordinates : Squish version [6.4.1]

Tags: python, testing, squish

How do i use touch and Drag option on Squish [6.4.1] without x,y,dx dy co-ordinates?

I have the mapped object for the container which i want to touch and drag(Slider function)

When i recorded using a dummy test case to understand Co-ordinates, it gives me more than 4 co-ordinates

touchAndDrag(waitForObject(names.ControllerDialogStackView), 157, 176, 1, 35, 0, 940)

Froglogic suggested that it uses 4 co-ordinates to located the object and the drag them either horizontal or vertical

touchAndDrag(objectOrName, x, y, dx, dy);

touchAndDrag(objectOrName, x, y, dx, dy, modifiers);

This function performs a touch-based drag operation. It initiates a touch drag of the specified objectOrName widget starting at position x and y (in the objectOrName widget's coordinates). The objectOrName widget is dragged by dx pixels horizontally and by dy pixels vertically.

Reference:  https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-qtconvenience.html

Comment: This link might help answering my question :
https://www.froglogic.com/blog/multi-touch-gesture-support-in-squish-5-1/

I am so close to getting my answer! 1

Answer (score 1):

That last parameter specifies the number of milliseconds after the touch, and before the drag. (This is sometimes required for special drag modes in applications.) This is being recorded when the recorded action consisted of slightly more milliseconds after the touch, as far as I can tell.

Leaving out those relative coordinates is logically impossible, because for a drag you need a direction and an extent, and that is what these coordinates express.

Comment: I was able to avoid the last 2 digits which represent milliseconds. I am down to 4 co-ordinates (x, y, dx, dy), which went perfect with my test case.